# ReferenceError in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I've got a problem with my web application. Firebug console gives me a "ReferenceError" that nearly every function is not found. I don't really know. I didn't even change stuff in some of the functions.
A snippet of my code:

```
<body>
...
<tr id="08">
    <td>08:00</td>
    <td id="mo08" onclick="go(this)"> </td>
    ....
</body>
```

Neither the `onclick` functions work nor the `<body onload=function()>` works.
I've tried to put the script into the header, but it ain't working, neither beneath the body.

```
function go(element) { 
  var ident = element.id;
  windowOpener("SomePage.jsp?i="+ident);
  checkDataBase();
}
```

Comment: I dont know anything about JSP so I could be wrong but... Aren't you missing `function ` before go?

Comment: only forgot it in this post.. I've got it in my code. Still thanks

Comment: Please provide a code snippet which can reproduce your error.

Comment: What line does the error occur on? What is `checkDataBase()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue now. The Problem were my tries to connect to my mysql server and get some data from it. After i deleted it out, everything worked fine for me. 
The Error occured in Line 1 Column 1, so i didn't have any clues, where to find my error.
I Thank you all for your Time and Effort.

Answer (score 0):

There could be any error in your file of javascript before this function i.e.
if functions are written in following order like

```
function foo1() {} /* If it contains error then 
functions below it will not be able to recognised by compiler */ 
    function foo2() {}
    function go() {}
```

so check for error before `go()` defination